# Numerical formatting of label ticks for charts in bokeh

Tags: python, anaconda, bokeh

Consider the following scatter plot example.

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

p = Scatter(df, x='colA', y='colB', title="Foo", color="navy",
            xlabel="A", ylabel="B", tools="hover")
```

I would like to change the formatting of the tick labels for one axis:

When I try with:

```
p.xaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0%")
```

I get:

```
Chart object has no attribute xaxis
```

Why? How can I access the figure of the chart?

Comment: What's the value for df?

Comment: @palfrey `df` is a Pandas `dataframe`.

Answer (score 3):

you have to do `p._xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0%")`

Comment: Not sure if still relevant, but I had to do `p.xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0%")` (without the undercore in `xaxis`)